# Generate test coverage for JavaScript client

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, integration-testing, code-coverage

We have an application that has an Angular front end, Java backend. We are using selenium (via Jenkins) to run a set of regression/integration tests against it.

We would like to be able to produce a report showing what areas of the code are covered by the tests. JaCoCo hooked in to the JVM would give us the coverage report for the Java code, but is there an equivalent to show us what % of the JS code is being exercised by the tests?

The instance of the application being tested isn't on the same server as the tests being run, or the jenkins server

Comment: https://medium.com/@the1mills/front-end-javascript-test-coverage-with-istanbul-selenium-4b2be44e3e98 (Istanbul Javascript code coverage) . Code coverage should be done for Unit testing rather than end to end tests.

Comment: @Rahul L, agreed. Its a request from our QA team to "prove" the auto tests are adequate

Answer (score 0):

Although doing code coverage for end to end test is not best practice. Unit test are the ones responsible for doing it.

There are tools to automate this.

Looks at this a see if this fits your requirement.

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/generate-code-coverage-report-from-running-e2e-test-with-cypress-io-aaf6d47499e8